# How to delete selected 100's of temp database in easy way

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

How to delete selected 100's of database in an easy way? I'm using SQL Server.

Example:

```
dbo.temp1
dbo.temp2
dbo.temp3
.
.
.
dbo.temp98
dbo.temp99
dbo.temp100
dbo.temp101
dbo.temp102
```

I just want to delete `dbo.temp1` to `dbo.temp100`.

Comment: You could use the undocumented `sp_MSForEachTable` stored procedure to run a script for every table. This script would check the name and drop it. You can probably find an example of this somewhere. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2007/10/23/60383.aspx

Answer (score 2):

First run this to check it lists only the tables you want to drop:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'IF LEFT(''?'',11) = ''[dbo].[temp''  PRINT ''?'''
```

If it does, run this:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'IF LEFT(''?'',11) = ''[dbo].[temp''  DROP TABLE ?'
```